# Проблема с подключением JavaFX

Tags: java, windows, javafx, intellij-idea

Я только новичок в программировании, прошу, помогите мне. Решил подключить JavaFX, но IntelliJ IDEA упорно не хочет видеть её, уже перепробовал всё, что нашёл в сети. ОС - Windows.
Заранее спасибо.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Можно открыть надстройку мавена и добавить туда проект.

Comment: @RomanC А как? Что нужно вводить в поле "keyboard or class name to search..."?

Answer (score 0):

В переменной окружения PATH вы указали путь C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11-0.3 к внешнему jdk-11. Однако в окне проекта (см.копию экрана) в разделе External Libraries отсутствует ссылка на внешний jdk. Дело в том, что Intellij IDEA содержит собственный (внутренний) экземпляр jdk (вот путь к нему - C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.2.2\jbr), так же 11 версии. Можно использовать любой из них, но один. Для выбора внешнего jdk открываем File/Project Structure/SDK, указываем нужный jdk (контролируем имя в строке *Name:* и путь в строке *Jdk home path:* (должен совпадать с указанным в переменной PATH). При выборе внешнего jdk в разделе External Libraries окна проекта появиться ссылка на него. Пока же там присутствуют необходимые ссылки на модули библиотеки JavaFX.